# Quickbooks Online filtering with Signpost returns 401 error

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online, signpost

I was able to get Signpost work with QuickBooks Online using HttpPost. However when I tried querying with filters, I got 401 error every time. After contacting support, I was informed that this is a known bug. They pointed me to an example in C#. I am using Signpost oauth library in Java. The C# example doesn't make sense to me since I don't have those functions available in Signpost. Also I don't understand what exactly I need to do.

One side note: I had to use HttpClient for this content type:  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". This is the limitation that comes from Signpost.

Unauthorized OAuth Token: signature_invalid401SERVER

The C# workaround example:
https://gist.github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/6024616

```
/* filtering fails with 401 error */
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost requestHp = new HttpPost("https://qbo.intuit.com/qbo28/resource/accounts/v2/670436015");
    requestHp.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    BasicHttpEntity  filter = new BasicHttpEntity();
    filter.setContent(new StringInputStream("Filter=Name :EQUALS: Continuing"));
    requestHp.setEntity(filter);
    CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(getOauthConsumerKey(), getOauthConsumerSecret());
    consumer.setTokenWithSecret(getOauthAccessToken(),getOauthAccessTokenSecret());
    consumer.sign(requestHp);

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(requestHp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AcctNum is not a valid filter for QBO Account entity.

Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0400_quickbooks_online/account#Attributes_Supporting_Filtering_and_Sorting

You can use 'Name' attribute as filter.

PFB code snippet

**Using java devkit**

```
public List<QBAccount> testGetAll() {
    QBAccountQuery accountQuery = new QBAccountQuery(context);
    accountQuery.setName("BankCharges");

    final List<QBAccount> entityList = new ArrayList<QBAccount>();
    try {
        QBAccountService service = QBServiceFactory.getService(context, QBAccountService.class);
            List<QBAccount> qbAccountList = service.getAccounts(context, accountQuery);
            for (QBAccount each : qbAccountList) {
                entityList.add(each);
            }
    } catch (QBInvalidContextException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return entityList;
}
```

Endpoint - https://qbo.intuit.com/qbo1/resource/accounts/v2/188712345

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

post data to end point: Filter= Name :EQUALS: BankCharges

**Using Signpost**

```
public class PocApiCall {

    static String accesstoken = "";
    static String accessstokensecret = "";
    static String appToken = "";
    static String oauth_consumer_key = "";
    static String oauth_consumer_secret = "";
    static String realmID = "";
    static String dataSource = "";
    static String url = "";

    PocApiCall() {
        setupQBO();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        PocApiCall apiCall = new PocApiCall();
        apiCall.testLikeDevkit();
    }

    private void testLikeDevkit() {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost requestHp = new HttpPost(url);
        requestHp.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        BasicHttpEntity filter = new BasicHttpEntity();

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Filter", "Name :EQUALS: BankCharges"));
            requestHp.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8"));

            CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(oauth_consumer_key, oauth_consumer_secret);
            consumer.setTokenWithSecret(accesstoken, accessstokensecret);
            consumer.sign(requestHp);

            debugRequestValues(requestHp);

            HttpResponse execute = client.execute(requestHp);

            System.out.println(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(execute.getEntity().getContent())).readLine());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {   
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void debugRequestValues(HttpPost requestHp) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Method - " + requestHp.getRequestLine().getMethod());
        System.out.println("URI - " + requestHp.getRequestLine().getUri());
        Header[] allHeaders = requestHp.getAllHeaders();
        for(Header h : allHeaders){
            System.out.println("Name - " + h.getName() + " Value - " + h.getValue());
        }

        if(requestHp.getEntity() != null){
        System.out.println(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(requestHp.getEntity().getContent())).readLine());
        }
    }

    private static void setupQBO() {
        System.out.println("QBO token setup");
        accesstoken = "your tokens";
        accessstokensecret = "your tokens";
        appToken = "your tokens";
        oauth_consumer_key = "your tokens";
        oauth_consumer_secret = "your tokens";
        realmID = "688779980";
        dataSource = "QBO";
        url = "https://qbo.intuit.com/qbo1/resource/accounts/v2/123459980";
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks but that was not the problem. I just changed to use Name but still got the 401 error.

    filter.setContent(new StringInputStream("Filter=Name :EQUALS: Continuing"));
    
     <FaultInfo xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/baseexceptionmodel/xsd"><Message>Unauthorized OAuth Token: signature_invalid</Message><ErrorCode>401</ErrorCode><Cause>SERVER</Cause></FaultInfo>

Comment: while setting the entity(filter), you should use UrlEncodedFormEntity.
I have added the full working code snippet in my post. It worked fine for me. Please let me know if it helps.

Thanks

Comment: Manas, can you take a look at my other post? It seems that VendorCredit requires ItemId, which seems odd since it worked for us in the past. Our clients don't use ItemId. Is there a workaround for this? Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748148/quickbooks-vendor-credit-error-message

Comment: Hii Manas, Is there any restriction to create Customer using API on Trial version?

Comment: No. Are you facing any issue ? You can share the request and response xmls here.

Comment: Hi Manas .I want to make Android/iOS application by using quickbooks apis.But I am not able to find something relevant to start with as all the example are for the web. So you please suggest me something from where i can start with.

Comment: Hi Nitesh, 'Connect to QB' wizard doesn't work well in native mobile app. You need to have a standard webcomponent(with C2QB implementation) using which end users will generated Accesstoken and AccessSecret corresponding to their QBO account. You can have a middleware service which will manage all those tokens and expose an endpoint(securely) using which you're mobile app will retrive tokens before making any qbo endpoint call. Plz refer -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25153317/how-to-get-new-token-after-calling-reconnect-api-of-intuit. Thanks