# quickbooks vendor credit error message

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

When I sent the following XML to QuickBooks Desktop cloud, I received the following error which I don't understand. Googled but didn't find anything relating. Does anyone know what the source column is?

error message received:
p_validate_txn_ln - unable to find src_column_name_id per ref id acc_id = 39 idDomain = QB

```
<Object xsi:type="VendorCredit"><Header>
<DocNumber>8D1FC366607</DocNumber>
<TxnDate>2013-09-11</TxnDate>
<Note>Expense Report 09/11/2013 #2</Note>
<VendorName>E100</VendorName>
<TotalAmt>-25.00</TotalAmt>
<APAccountName>Accounts Payable</APAccountName></Header>
<Line>
<Desc>Airfare:</Desc>
<Amount>25.00</Amount>
<ClassId idDomain="QB">5</ClassId>
<ReimbursableInfo>
<CustomerId idDomain="QB">5</CustomerId>
<JobId idDomain="QB">6</JobId>
</ReimbursableInfo>
<BillableStatus>NotBillable</BillableStatus>
<AccountId idDomain="QB">39</AccountId>
</Line>
</Object>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/articles/SLN74445

QuickBooks has detected that you have no items When trying to enter an Invoice or a Sales Receipt without an item this warning is received:
QuickBooks has detected that you have no items or that one or more of your amounts are not associated with items. Please enter an item.
Why this is happening
If "Require Accounts" is checked in the Preferences this warning will occur.
How to fix it
  To be able to enter in an Invoice or Sales Receipt without an Item on it:
1.  Click the Edit Menu.
2.  Click Preferences...
3.  Click Accounting Preference> Company Preferences.
4.  Uncheck Require accounts.
5.  Click OK.
You will now be able to enter an Invoice or a Sales Receipt without an item on it.

Answer (score 0):

Although the docs mention AccountId as a required field, it is not(the docs might be slightly off). You can ignore it. if you chooss to add it then all fields related to Items need to included.
Instead  ItemId is a required field. So, please include it in your request.
Please refer:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference/vendorcredit

I created a vendor create request as follows and was able to get the correct response.
Request-

```
<Add xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" RequestId="Szey2z7hrGf888888888jfc5hrGSYg99" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2 ./RestDataFilter.xsd">
<Object xsi:type="VendorCredit">
<Header>
    <DocNumber>8D1FC366607</DocNumber>
    <TxnDate>2013-09-11</TxnDate>
    <Note>Expense Report 09/11/2013 #2</Note>
    <VendorName>TestVendor4</VendorName>
    <TotalAmt>-25.00</TotalAmt>
    <APAccountName>Accounts Payable</APAccountName>
</Header>
<Line>
    <Desc>Airfare:</Desc>
    <Amount>25.00</Amount>
    <ClassId idDomain="QB">1</ClassId>
    <ReimbursableInfo>
        <CustomerId idDomain="QB">31</CustomerId>           
    </ReimbursableInfo>
    <BillableStatus>NotBillable</BillableStatus>
    <ItemId idDomain="QB">12</ItemId>       
</Line>
</Object>
</Add>
```

Response-

```
<RestResponse xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
  <Success RequestId="Szey2z7hrGf888888888jfc5hrGSYg99">
<ObjectRef>
  <Id idDomain="NG">1925041</Id>
  <SyncToken>1</SyncToken>
  <LastUpdatedTime>2013-09-12T07:50:34Z</LastUpdatedTime>
</ObjectRef>
<RequestName>VendorCreditAdd</RequestName>
<ProcessedTime>2013-09-12T07:50:34Z</ProcessedTime>
  </Success>
</RestResponse>
```

**Edit for the questions asked:**
**Please note:**
VendorCredit is an AP transaction representing a credit from a third party for returned goods or services not rendered. In QuickBooks desktop versions, a vendor credit is also known as a "bill credit". That is, it is a credit that a vendor owes you because you overpaid your bill, returned merchandise, or for some other reason. The VendorCredit is not applied until it is referenced in a Bill Payment transaction.
Note: A VendorCredit should not be confused with a Credit Memo, which is something you owe your customer

**ItemId refers to those items for which the credit is made.** You can get the ItemId by calling the Item api in QBD. Refer is in your request here.
Since, you are not mentioning the itemid in your request xml, you got the response but the sync to QB desktop file failed. You Vendor credit object must have errored out.

To check if the entity is in an error state, you can check by executing a query and setting ErroredObjectsOnly="true".

http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0100_Calling_Data_Services/0015_Retrieving_Objects#Objects_in_Error_State

If the entity is in error state, you can query for the specific reason using the SyncStatus API:

http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0600_Object_Reference/SyncStatus

**Please add the itemid reference in your request and it should work.**

Comment: What should be the value for the ItemId? Where do I find that out?

Comment: Are you sure of this? Because the code used to work for Quickbooks Desktop, using AccountId, not ItemId.

Comment: I removed AccountId and didn't include ItemId. Was able to post and there was no exception. However after running sync manager, I don't see the Bill Refund objects. So it was not added, even there was no error.

Comment: After not including AccountId or ItemId, I was able to send the create VendorCredit object fine. Got success response. However after I ran sync manager, go to QB Desktop, find the Account, the vendorCredit is not there. Any advice?

Comment: Is there to create VendorCredit not using ItemId? The code used to work using AccountId. Our app doesn't support ItemId.

Comment: A VendorCredit should not be confused with a Credit Memo, which is something you owe your customer. In itemId reference will be required even if you enter AccountId. But if you enter AccountId, then a whole lot of other fields are mandatory. You can test this yourself when you get a list of mandatory fields along with AccountId in the error response.

Answer (score 0):

After not including AccountId or ItemId, I was able to send the create VendorCredit object fine. Got success response. However after I ran sync manager, go to QB Desktop, find the Account, the vendorCredit is not there. Any advice? 
XML sent:

```
<Object xsi:type="VendorCredit">
    <Header>
        <DocNumber>58B58878D79</DocNumber>
        <TxnDate>2013-09-12</TxnDate>
        <Note>Expense Report 09/12/2013 #2</Note>
        <VendorName>E100</VendorName>
        <TotalAmt>-43.80</TotalAmt>
        <APAccountName>Accounts Payable</APAccountName>
    </Header>
    <Line>
        <Desc>Advertising:</Desc>
        <Amount>43.80</Amount>
        <ClassId idDomain="QB">1</ClassId>
        <ReimbursableInfo>
            <CustomerId idDomain="QB">4</CustomerId>
            <JobId idDomain="QB">8</JobId>
        </ReimbursableInfo>
    </Line>
</Object>
```

Response received:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RestResponse>
    <Success RequestId="4a3f1538a01b4a4dac6f03406c6710c7">
    <VendorCredit>
    <Id idDomain="NG">14542796</Id>
    <SyncToken>1</SyncToken>
    <MetaData>
        <CreatedBy>app</CreatedBy>
        <CreateTime>2013-09-12T23:41:38Z</CreateTime>
        <LastModifiedBy>app</LastModifiedBy>
        <LastUpdatedTime>2013-09-12T23:41:38Z</LastUpdatedTime>
    </MetaData>
    <Synchronized>false</Synchronized>
    <Header>
        <DocNumber>58B58878D79</DocNumber>
        <TxnDate>2013-09-12T00:00:00Z</TxnDate>
        <Note>Expense Report 09/12/2013 #2</Note>
        <VendorName>E100</VendorName>
        <TotalAmt>-43.8</TotalAmt>
        <APAccountName>Accounts Payable</APAccountName>
    </Header>
    <Line>
        <Id idDomain="NG">50786642</Id>
        <Desc>Advertising:</Desc>
        <Amount>43.8</Amount>
        <ClassId idDomain="QB">1</ClassId>
        <ReimbursableInfo>
        <    CustomerId idDomain="QB">4</CustomerId>
            <JobId idDomain="QB">8</JobId>
        </ReimbursableInfo>
    </Line>
</VendorCredit>
<RequestName>VendorCreditAdd</RequestName><ProcessedTime>2013-09-12T23:41:38Z</ProcessedTime>
</Success>
</RestResponse>
```