# QuickBook Online API integration oauth issue in Android

Tags: android, oauth, quickbooks-online

I am trying to integrate Quickbook API for android but I am not able to find the way to authenticate and access api. They have provided sample for java swing and .net but there is nothing for android. I have tried to use oauth but cant find correct url and parameter for oauth.

Please guide me how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: Please post your question on IPP Live Community : https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting consumer key, consumer secret and apptoken, you can follow the link below.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0010_signup

Using the above tokens and Oauth playground tool, you can get access token and access secret corresponding to you QBO account
https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth

After getting all these tokens, you can use SignPost lib to call QBO REST endpoints from your android client application.
You can follow this SO post - [Quickbooks Online filtering with Signpost returns 401 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223603/quickbooks-online-filtering-with-signpost-returns-401-error)

(you'll find all endpoint related details in the QBAPI docs. 
QB API Docs Link - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi

Hope it will be useful.

Thanks